# scanf, getchar() and negative numbers in C

Tags: c

I'm looking at past papers for my exam. I have this one question that I don't know why this is the correct answer.

4. A loop is required to read a negative integer from the user into a variable `c`. It should ignore all characters
   inputted by the user, until a valid negative number is entered. For example, if the user types `x-x-x89--90`,
   then `c` should be filled with `-90`. Which one of the program excerpts below is correct:

(b)

```
int c=0;
while (c>=0)
    while (scanf("%d", &c)!=1 && getchar());
```

^ This is the correct answer, I've run it myself and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Well: `scanf`... tries to read in an integral value (positive or negative); the return value of `scanf` is the number of correctly read in formats like `%d`, so you may expect `1` for a successful read of `"%d"`. If `scanf` returns `1`,  the inner loop exits; otherwise, `getchar()` is called which takes a character from the input stream and leads to the next try of `scanf`. The outer loop then makes sure that positive values are ignored.

Note that the "correct" answer has a bug if "end-of-file" is entered. This will lead to an endless loop then. So I'd actually adapt the code as follows:

```
int c=0;
while (c>=0 && !feof(stdin))
    while (scanf("%d", &c)!=1 && getchar() != EOF);
```

Comment: A rare example of a plausible use of `feof()`.